# Why should I encrypt data at rest if the data sever is behind vpn?

Tags: vpn, disk-encryption

If the server is behind a vpn anyway, wouldn't it be secure?

I'm looking at aws's encryption at rest feature, and trying to understand why I would use it. If someone manages to get through my vpn, wouldn't they be able to access the encrypted data using the same key?

Comment: It's a defence-in-depth measure. Maybe they *somehow* have your data without also having the access that would give them the key. Maybe they have an errant page of memory that was once part of the instance storage from your EC2 instance, for example. Maybe somebody has kicked down the doors at the data centre and they've run off with the hard drives. Generally you want to protect against the attack vectors that you haven't yet imagined.